# How to Bind data to DataGridComboBoxColumn in DataGrid using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

This is driving me crazy. I have a DataGrid which has a DataGridComboBoxColumn which I want the user to be able to use to select from. This is the basic outline of my grid.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GoalList}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding LifeAreaList}" Header="Life Area"/>
<DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The DataGrid is bound to a collection of objects of type Goal. Each Goal has a property of type LifeArea. Each LifeArea has the properties LifeAreaId and Name.

The data context contains an observable collection of Goals: GoalList and a list of Life Areas: LifeAreaList. I want the user to be able to select a different life area for a goal. Also the name of the life area needs to be the displayed value.

EDIT

---

The solution is that the ItemsSource for the DataGridComboBoxColumn has to be set as a static resource. Another option is to set the ItemsSource through code.

In the end I have:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="_lifeAreaComboBoxColumn" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding LifeArea}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Header="Life Area">
```

In the code behind I set the ItemsSource:

```
_lifeAreaComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource = LifeAreaDAL.GetLifeAreas();
```

When I get a chance I'll convert this to a StaticResource.

Comment: Don't you need a DisplayMemberPath in your DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Comment: I've tried but nothing displays in the dropdown.

Comment: Not saying this will fix it, but how does the `GridComboBoxColumn` know which life area is selected? You need to bind `SelectedItem` to something, too.

Comment: Have you checked whether you have any binding error and PropertyChanged is getting triggered

Answer (score 22):

You need to do something like this (don't shoot the messenger):

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Life Area" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedLifeArea}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding LifeAreaList}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding LifeAreaList}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Oh man thank you so much!!!  I was trying to find a solution for this now for 3 weeks.  Why is the combobox inside a DataGrid so odd? Why isn't it following the logical tree as you would expect?  I mean DataGrid was beta for a long time until it got integrated into .NET 4.0.  How comes they didnt fix it?  I am worried about these things, I wonder how do I learn this stuff? Where do I need to read to come up for a solution for this particular problem? How did you figure this out please? :D

Comment: I needed to add setters for DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath for the ComboBox style.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to binding your SelectedItem, I am guessing that your SelectedLifeArea property is not obtained directly from LifeAreaList so when comparing the two values they are returning false, even if the name and id match. You probably need to overwrite the .Equals function of the LifeArea object to return true if the Ids of both objects match

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is LifeArea)
    {
        return this.Id == (obj as LifeArea).Id;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Up can also use a DataGridTemplateColumn and just put a ComboBox in it and then wire the appropriate events to it.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Alpha">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="models:MyModelDescription">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AlphaLevels, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Alpha, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```